# How to Monitor ruby process ?

Tags: ruby, foreman

What is the best way to monitore Ruby process ( Not Rails ), I tried to use Newrelic but it seems it is designed for Rails .

I'm using distributed Ruby processes with foreman, the processes communicate with RabbitMQ queuing system, and I'm looking for a tool that can trace my queries and other parameters specially that I'm using active record with most of my models .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NewRelic is still viable for Ruby apps that are non-Rails. The downside is you have to manually instrument your code with trace calls. [NewRelic's documentation](https://newrelic.com/docs/docs/custom-metric-collection) (scroll down to *Adding Method Tracers (Ruby)*) shows how to setup custom tracing for your application. Then you can use the NewRelic website as usual to inspect the runtime of your app.

I have done this for Java apps, but not a Ruby app. One thing to look out for is that custom traces will show up in the *Background Issues* area, not under *Web Transactions* (for obvious reasons). *Database* calls should be in the correct area.

The NewRelic support is very good, I have work with them several times to debug an issue. If you have an issue with the custom tracing, they will help sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

try [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)

Comment: I'm not looking for something to run and stop the process i'm already using foreman to do so , but i'm looking more for something showing some statistics just like newrelic